# How can I get results of one search query filter only in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am creating a real estate project, which will have a search option for different pages with different search filters.

Here is one example of the search view

```
<form class="form-row basic-select-wrapper" method="POST" action="{{route('filter')}}">
    @csrf
    {{-- <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="prop_name">
    </div> --}}
    <div class="form-group col-lg col-md-6">
        <label>Property type</label>
        <select name="type_id" class="form-control basic-select">
            <option>Select Type</option>
            @foreach ($types as $type)
            @if ($type->status == 1)
                <option value="{{ $type->id }}">{{ $type->name }}</option>
            @endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg col-md-6">
        <label>Property Category</label>
        <select name="cat_id" class="form-control basic-select">
            <option>Select Category</option>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg col-md-6">
        <label>Location</label>
        <select name="loc_id" class="form-control basic-select">
            <option>Select Location</option>
            @foreach ($locations as $location)
                <option value="{{ $location->id }}">{{ $location->loc_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg col-md-6">
        <label>Budget</label>
        <select name="start_price" class="form-control basic-select">
            <option>Select Budget</option>
            @foreach($price['price'] as $key => $val)
                <option value="{{$key}}">{{$val}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg col-md-6">
        <label>Bedroom(s)</label>
        <select name="min_bed" class="form-control basic-select">
            <option>Select Bedroom</option>
                <option value="0">studio</option>
                <option value="1">one bedroom</option>
                <option value="2">two bedroom</option>
                <option value="3">three bedroom</option>
                <option value="4">four bedroom</option>
                <option value="5">five bedroom</option>
                <option value="6">six bedroom</option>
                <option value="7">seven bedroom</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="advanced-search" id="advanced-search">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <div class="mt-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary align-items-center" type="submit"><i
                            class="fas fa-search mr-1"></i><span>Search</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my search controller

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use App\Models\Listing;
use App\ListingSearch\ListingSearch;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function filter(Request $request)
    {
        return ListingSearch::apply($request);
    }

}
```

Now, to implement this since there are multiple search filters and I wanted to simplify it. Here is the folder structure
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ej2g.png)

Here is the Listitng Search Class

```
<?php

namespace App\ListingSearch;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

use App\Models\Listing;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ListingSearch
{
    public static function apply(Request $filters)
    {
        $query = static::applyDecoratorsFromRequest(
                $filters, (new Listing)->newQuery()
            );
        // Get the results and return them.
        return static::getResults($query);
    }

    private static function applyDecoratorsFromRequest(Request $request, Builder $query)
    {
        foreach ($request->all() as $filterName => $value) {

            $decorator = static::createFilterDecorator($filterName);

            if (static::isValidDecorator($decorator)) {
                $query = $decorator::apply($query, $value);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }

    private static function createFilterDecorator($name)
    {
        return __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Filters\\' .
            str_replace(' ', '',
                ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $name)));
    }

    private static function isValidDecorator($decorator)
    {
        return class_exists($decorator);
    }

    private static function getResults(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->get();
    }
}
```

here is an example of one of the filters CATID for category

```
<?php

namespace App\ListingSearch\Filters;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class CatId implements Filter
{
    public static function apply($builder, $value)
    {
        return $builder->where('cat_id', $value);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that I have to enter all the required filters to get a result, otherwise if I only fill one filter I get null results, for example I want only apartments, without entering location or  category. How can I achieve this?

[search query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNKGD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to filter the $value before stacking them in your where?

```
    if (!empty($value)) {

    }
```

empty() will take care of filtering out the empty and null values. So you end up adding to your query filter values that actually exists.

EDIT

```
    foreach ($request->all() as $filterName => $value) {

        if (!empty($value)) {
            $decorator = static::createFilterDecorator($filterName);

            if (static::isValidDecorator($decorator)) {
                $query = $decorator::apply($query, $value);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2

Your option tag has no value attribute defined and there for is not empty when posted to your controller because the browser defaults to the value inside the tag (Select Type, Select Category ect). You need to provide the value attribute as empty so that the POST does not use the inner text like this:

```
<option value="">Select Type</option>
[...]
<option value="">Select Category</option>
[...]
<option value="">Select Location</option>
[...]
<option value="">Select Budget</option>
```

Then if (!empty($value)) {} can do it's thing

Comment: If I input 3 filters, that is, location, type, and category, I get a result of filtered query. If I only input location w/o type and category, no results are displayed @Patrick

Comment: Please see my edit ... looks to me like your not filtering out the empty values.

Comment: Even with the edit added, it is still not filtering only one query out of the three @Patrick

Comment: Can you share me the actual query it's passing on to MySQL? Also, you might wana dump $request->all() and see what's inside. Take a look at the POST headers in the browser console to to see what the values are for the empty request. It's might not be NULL or empty.

Comment: when I factor in the 3 queries, location, type and category I get a result of the filtered values. When I just factor one, like location, when i dd($request) I get [ ] @patrick

Comment: DD inside applyDecoratorsFromRequest() like this dd($request->all()); (Before the loop.)

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "gSEjPfVG83do6GWSCEZv9cTPYUFmMorCtJsJMd5Y"
  "type_id" => "1"
  "cat_id" => "3"
  "loc_id" => "7"
]

Comment: the above is for 3 queries when I just put 1 array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "gSEjPfVG83do6GWSCEZv9cTPYUFmMorCtJsJMd5Y"
  "type_id" => "1"
  "cat_id" => "Select Category"
  "loc_id" => "Select Location"
]

Comment: Well theres your problem lol the values are not empty or null. Let me edit My awnser

Comment: you are very right, I adjusted the option value, now its working. Thanks alot for the assistance